# Last Logon error when Logging in using GPO setting

Tags: windows-7, login, group-policy

Trying to get my domain to show the last successful login by users on their Windows 7 machines. I have enabled the following Group Policy Setting:

```
Computer Configuration| Policies | Administrative Templates | Windows Components | Windows Logon Options | Display information about previous logons during user logon
```

When users login they get this message:

> Security policies on this computer are set to display information about the last interactive logon. Windows could not retrieve this information. Please contact your network administrator for assistance

And then prevents users from logging in.

It works fine on my Server 2008 R2 machines but not my Windows 7. I have Googled for an answer to this question but people just trying to disable the setting. I want to get it working. Has anyone got this working or had this issue?

Comment: Is the Domain Functional Level at least Windows Server 2008?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the past when I've had this error it has resulted when not all computers correctly have the setting. Most importantly, all the DCs need to have the setting enabled.

Comment: This is correct. Turns out the Domain Controller did not enable the setting before the computer did so it did not have the information to send to the client when it asked for it. Found this out on my own but you beat me to typing out the answer. :)